# 1800+ unanswered DevOps questions at SO

Tags: discussion

Currently, there are almost [2000 unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=devops%20answers%3A0) at SO mentioning DevOps.

Do you see any sense to move them to [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) where there might be a higher chance to get an answer?

- This post is not meant to criticize the quality of the SO community
- The DevOps SE gets relatively low number of questions while the user base is still growing. I support the idea that SE sites exist to provide a focus on highly specialized topics.
- DevOps questions are not off-topic on SO in my opinion, but it is the primary topic at DevOps SE providing more room for interdisciplinary/holistic aspects for answers like methodology, culture, project management.
- From DevOps point of view, the job of moving questions by selected criteria can be automated, so not manual effort per question is required, so this alone should not be an obstacle. At least some assessment on it could provide insights and at least partly automation for whatever steps.

Comment: Have you asked on the [DevOps Meta](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com) whether they even *want* all of these questions there?

Comment: we do :-) this questions results from a meta discussion there. https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330/risk-assessment-of-getting-closed-during-beta  we are still growing on users but the daily asked question average is growing very slowly towards SE standard of 10. Ideally, therefore we would get the questions not all at one bunch but in small batches from time to time. Automation logic could be for example "if a question containing word DevOps gets at least 1 upvote and does not get answered for more than period X, move to DevOps SE"

Comment: In my opinion it is a pitty that this question is downvoted immediately. We are trying to get the DevOps SE out of beta for already two years. It is a great opportunity for SO to get rid of out of scope questions and to focus on development.

Comment: Who says they are out of scope? It's perfectly possible they are in-scope on both sites.

Comment: @RobertLongson "on/off" topic is a very simple binary qualifier; in terms of a hypothetical knowledge graph either a clustering algorithm many questions related to DevOps might get different weightings towards one or another site, or maybe project management/workplace for example. I think it's not about "out of scope" but about higher chance for posters to get an answer in case "not answered for long time" means "might faster get attention where DevOps is primary topic"

Comment: There's a *seperate* devops site? Is that not a joke site, to troll the people who work on "devops teams"?

Comment: hi, @CodyGray, may I ask you the following: which steps could a DevOps SE moderator undertake to migrate / support migrating an unanswered DevOps question to the DevOps SE site unless it is older than 60 days? We are not talking about large batches at a time.

Comment: There is a wholeheckofalot of "don't do it!" advice possible.  But lets keep it simple, the entire undertaking is based on a mistaken assumption.  Beta sites are no longer closed, they can stay in beta forever.  The term is meaningless today.

Comment: @HansPassant this is a great piece of information! Is there some official information on that? Googling gives me that some beta sites were graduated by the age, and the Astronomy site for example got closed once. Crazy enough the Startups SE was founded twice and got closed twice.

Comment: Steps: Find good (well-asked) questions on SO that have been ***closed*** (we don’t migrate questions that are on-topic for SO: on sites with overlapping scope, it is asker’s choice), and flag these questions for diamond moderator attention. Make sure to mention that DevOps agrees with the requested migration (maybe link this Meta question). If there’s a large batch at once, maybe ping me with a PasteBin or something containing links.

Comment: thank you, @CodyGray!

Answer (score 12):

Most of them are likely too old to move. Moderators can only move posts if they are less than 60 days old.

Just because they might be on topic on DevOps doesn't make them off-topic here.

Do you really think we want to get our moderators and the devops moderators to go through 2000 questions asking the devops moderators whether each one is on-topic on their site so they can be migrated. Sounds like a lot of manual effort. If anyone wants to delete their question and re-ask it on the devops site they are free to do so.

There may be 2000 unanswered questions but there are more than 6000 questions in total so we've answered quite a lot and some of those 2000 might simply have an answer that's not yet been upvoted so it's not all doom and gloom with the status quo.

Comment: thank you for the answer, @Robert Longson! Though I do not agree that manual effort is really requirement, an automation could do the job if there would be a motivation to do so. I was not going to criticize SO community: to my opinion, SE sites exist to focus on more specialized topics.

Comment: Moderators here won't move questions unless a moderator there okays it.

Comment: please specify more detail what includes "moderator okaying it". Which steps could a DevOps SE moderator undertake to move an unanswered DevOps question to the DevOps SE site unless it is older than 60 days?

Comment: I don't know in detail since I'm not a moderator. If you reached out to Cody Gray via a comment on your question (rather than a comment here) then he might tell you more.

Comment: Not entirely true that mods here won’t migrate without approval from target site mods. We will. Getting approval from target site mods takes too long and involves too much overhead. We just make migration decisions by judgment call, looking for high-quality, off-topic questions that we think, by our best understanding of the target site’s scope and Help Center, would be well-received there. The sad truth is, most off-topic questions asked here are poor quality and/or off-topic everywhere, so we don’t migrate them.